# write mongoDB find query in java code

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to generate java code for below mongoDB query:

```
db.getCollection('dum_stats').find({ "engineNo": {$eq: 1} },{"sensorName": 1, "_id": false})
```

Solution:

```
Bson query = Filters.eq("engineNo", Integer.parseInt(machineId));
FindIterable<Document> listOfSensorNames = dbCollection.find(query).projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("sensorName"), Projections.exclude("_id")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what lib you gonna use to connect to mongo! we have at least this many libraries!

```
1. Morphia. Type-Safe Wrapper with DAO/Datastore abstractions.
2. Spring MongoDB. Provides Spring users with a familiar data access features including rich POJO mapping.
3. Morphium. Feature-rich POJO Mapper including features like declarative caching, cluster awareness, validation, partial updates supports aggregation framework.
4. Mungbean (w/clojure support).
5. DataNucleus JPA/JDO. JPA/JDO wrapper
6. lib-mongomapper. JavaBean Mapper (No annotations).
7. MongoJack. Uses jackson (annotations) to map to/from POJOs and has a simple wrapper around DBCollection to simply this.
8. Kundera. JPA compliant ORM. Works with multiple datastores.
9. MongoFS. Enhanced file storage library with support for file compression, encryption, and Zip file expansion. Can be used on top of a GridFS-compatible bucket.
9. Jongo. Query in Java as in mongo shell (using strings), unmarshall results into Java objects (using Jackson)
10. MongoLink. Object Document Mapper (ODM.) Uses a plain java DSL for mapping declaration.
11. Hibernate OGM. Provides Java Persistence support for MongoDB.
12. Morphix. Lightweight, easy-to-use POJO mapper, with object caching and lifecycle methods.
```

**update**
your request code with mongo java driver would look like this:

```
db.getCollection("dum_stats").find(
    eq("engineNo", "1")
).projection(
    fields(
        include("sensorName"),
        excludeId("_id")
    )
);
```

Comment: I am using the jar mongo-java-driver-3.3.0

Comment: check the answer :)

Comment: Actually, mongoDB query i have prioduced myself as of the question, now i want to generate equailent java code, this is where i am lagging.

Comment: this is the java code! I skipped the initializing part for db tho! check [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.3/builders/) for more options!

Comment: Yes your answer is correct, since i am new using mongoDB it was troubling me, now i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This link show all example for java : 
http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/